# Font sizing with rem

Tags: html, css

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
body { font-size: 1.4rem; } /* =14px */
h1   { font-size: 2.4rem; } /* =24px */
```

Hey guys, I am trying to work out the calculation.
How do we get 14px for body and 24px for h1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `html` is given a font size as a percentage, it is calculated based on the font size preference set by the user in their browser options. This is usually 16px as a "standard" across browsers, but of course it may vary based on the user's own settings.

62.5% of 16px is 10px, giving `html` an absolute font size of 10px. From there, it should be easy to work out the sizes for `body` and `h1`.

Comment: If this is true, doesn't asker have the right values already?

Comment: @TheZ: Yeah, I'm guessing the asker obtained those values from `getComputedStyle()` or browser developer tools, and is wondering how the browser arrived at those values.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks. I was about to come back to this thread as I just found out that 16px is the default browser font size before any styles applied. Yeap, I just copied & pasted the above code from somewhere and I am trying to figure how it works. This is the famous Richard Rutter 62.5% method.